# Mesh is flickering when mirror modifier is present and worse when subdivision surface is off

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

[image: Mesh with both subdivision and mirror modifier on]
First pic is mesh with both subvision surfaec and mirror modifier on, the part that has been merged centre is flickering. I can't add more edges, it will look weird and won't affect a thing.

[image: Mesh with subdivision off]
2nd pic is mesh with subdivision surface off, the flickering happens everywhere except the circled red face.

[image: stuff]
I needed to add lots of loopcuts to fix some of the flickering when subdivision is on

**I'm trying to do UV editing but this issue is getting in the way.**
[image]
file

Comment: Do you have clipping and merge turned on in the Mirror modifier?  If not, turn them on, select all of the points that are meant to lie on the mirror axis at 0 and move them along the axis until they won't move because of clipping.  If that doesn't work, maybe add your blend file to your question. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=GXDbK80Y" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/GXDbK80Y/)

Comment: yes i have both on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mirroring on an axis that is already mirrored (X) so you end up with overlapping faces. Disable the X axis of your *Mirror* modifier, or remove this part of your object.